# inserting results from one sqlite3 query into another table

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to search one table for its homeworkID once it has been selected, and another table for the first and surnames of the students who are in the class which the homework is being set to. I am able to successfully get both results I am looking for, when running print I get the correct homeworkID and I also print the correct names from the corresponding class. However I am having problems inserting these results together into a separate table, HomeworkSet, which includes the homeworkID of the homework being set and the first name and surname of the student being set.

```
        conn = sqlite3.connect('MyComputerScience.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        homeworkID = c.execute("SELECT HWID FROM HomeworkInfo WHERE HomeworkName = ?", (homeworktoset, )).fetchone()
        print (homeworkID)
        c.execute("SELECT FName || ' ' || SName FROM users WHERE ClassName = ?", (ClassName_SetHWR, ))
        homeworksetlist = c.fetchall()
        print (homeworksetlist)
        for i in (homeworksetlist):
            c.execute('insert INTO HomeworkSet (HWID, FName, SName)VALUES(?,?,?);', ((homeworkID), str(i), str(i), ))
            conn.commit()
```

Instead I get this message;

```
c.execute('insert INTO HomeworkSet (HWID, FName, SName)VALUES(?,?,?);', ((homeworkID), str(i), str(i), ))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Comment: A (error prone) guess: `c.execute(INSERT INTO HomeworkSet (HWID, FName, SName) VALUES (?, ?, ?);', (homeworkID[0], str(i), str(i), ))`

Comment: Sounds like you want `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html